# Product attribute not saving programmatically

Tags: magento-1.7, attributes, frontend, model

I am running a method to save attribute store view titles prgrammatically, but one attribute store view titles does not save when the method is run inside a loop. I thought it was a caching issue, but had no luck when I added the clear cache code like it says to do in this [example code](http://www.webspeaks.in/2012/05/addupdate-attribute-option-values.html). This method runs properly and saves correctly when not run in a loop or is run manually inside the admin UI.

What am I missing?

I have also tried to put a `sleep(1);` out of desperation without any luck.

The attribute store title is shown inside `$model` after `addData()` method.

```
$data = array();
$model = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute');
$model->load($attr_id);

$data['frontend_label'] = $attribute_title; // array of titles for store views
$data['option'] = array('value' => $attribute_arr); // array of option labels for store views

$model->addData($data);
$model->save();

$session = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session');

// Clear translation cache because attribute labels are stored in translation

Mage::app()->cleanCache(array(Mage_Core_Model_Translate::CACHE_TAG));
$session->setAttributeData(false);
```

e.g. of `$data['frontend_label']` on the first loop:

```
[frontend_label] => Array (
        [1] => Color2
        [2] => Cõôlõôr
        [3] => Còôlòôr
        [0] => Color
    )
```

On the next loop after the model saved once the attribute model is loaded again and `Array[2]` was not been saved:

```
[frontend_label] => Array (
        [1] => Color2
        [2] => Color3
        [3] => Còôlòôr
        [0] => Color
    )
```

EDIT:

controller action:

```
public function updateAction() {
  $success = TRUE;
  $end_count = 0;
  $start_count = 0;
  $translation = array();
  $gl_arr = Mage::helper("my_helper")->gl_get_all_completed_targets();
  foreach ($translation_arr as $translation) {
    $result_arr = Mage::helper("my_helper")->get_status_objects(FALSE);
    if ($result_arr[0]['status'] == Mage::helper("my_helper")->_get_submission_status_ready() ||
        $result_arr[0]['status'] == Mage::helper("my_helper")->_get_submission_status_error()) {
      try {
        Mage::helper("my_helper")->update_translated_record_in_magento($translation);
        $start_count++;
        }
      catch (SoapFault $sf) {
        $success = FALSE;
      }
      catch (Exception $ex) {
      $success = FALSE;
    }
  }
}
```

helper file (e.g. my_help.php):

```
public function update_translated_record_in_magento($translation) {

    $gl_object = $this->parse_target_xml($translation['translated_content']);
    $mapped_langs = $this->get_mapped_locales();
    $tgt_lang_store_id = $mapped_langs[$translation['target_locale']]['store_id'];

if ($gl_object['object_type'] == $this->_get_object_type_product_attributes()) {
      $attr_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute');
      $attr_model->load($gl_object['object_id']);

      $option_arr = array();
      $attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', $attr_model->attribute_code);
      foreach ($attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false) as $option) {
        $option_arr[$option['value']] = $option['label'];
      }

      $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load();
      $attribute_title = $product->getResource()->getAttribute($attr_model->attribute_code)->getStoreLabels();
      $attribute_title[0] = $attr_model->frontend_label;

      $stores = Mage::app()->getStores();
      $attribute_arr = array();
      foreach ($stores as $store_key => $object) {
        $store_id = Mage::app()->getStore($store_key)->getId();
        $config = Mage::getModel('eav/config');
        $get_attribute = $config->getAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, $attr_model->attribute_code);
        $attribute_val = $get_attribute->setStoreId($store_id)->getSource()->getAllOptions();

        unset($attribute_val[0]);

        foreach ($attribute_val as $val) {
          $attribute_arr[$val['value']][$store_id] = $val['label'];
        }

        foreach ($option_arr as $key => $option) {
          $attribute_arr[$key][0] = $option;
        }
     }

     $data = array();
     $data['frontend_label'] = $attribute_title;
     $data['option'] = array('value' => $attribute_arr);

     $attributes = $gl_object['attributes'];
     foreach ($attributes as $key => $attribute) {
       if ($key == 'frontend_label') {
         $data['frontend_label'][$tgt_lang_store_id] = $attribute;
       }
       else {
         if (!empty($option_arr[$key])) {
            $data['option']['value'][$key][$tgt_lang_store_id] = $attribute;
         }
       }
     }

    try {
      $attr_model->addData($this->filterPostData($data));
      $attr_model->save();
      $session = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session');

      Mage::app()->cleanCache(array(Mage_Core_Model_Translate::CACHE_TAG));
      $session->setAttributeData(false);
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
      $session = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session');
      $session->addError($e->getMessage());
      $session->setAttributeData($data);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Put everything in a `try-catch` and on `catch` print the error. Maybe something goes wrong during the save action.

Comment: @Marius in my code I have a try and catch I just did not put it here. No errors are displayed and nothing in the log. Quite strange.

Comment: I was able to run this code inside a `foreach` loop without any issues. Maybe it's a single part of the code or data that doesn't work. Can you post the full code you use? That way I can test with exactly the same code.

Comment: What is the loop syntax?

Comment: and it does it work if you manually save that product attribute with given values in the admin?

Comment: @Marius I have added the code to the question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Lucasmus it does indeed work if I do it manually; also works if I don't use a loop to insert values into multiple store views.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing this is a script that's running outside of the normal Magento structure and  you are including `app/Mage.php` and instantiating it with `Mage::app();`?

In that case the label might be saved on a different level than your store.
Try using the `emulate` functionality to save the model data in the right store view.

```
$appEmulation = Mage::getSingleton('core/app_emulation');
//Start environment emulation of the specified store
$initialEnvironmentInfo = $appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($storeId);
/*
 * Any code thrown here will be executed as we are currently running that store
 * with applied locale, design and similar
 */
//Stop environment emulation and restore original store
$appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation($initialEnvironmentInfo);
```

(source: [Inchoo](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/emulate-store-in-magento/))

Also try and reindex the data in your store. Start the script with setting indexes to manual

```
$processes = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->getProcessesCollection();
$processes->walk('setMode', array(Mage_Index_Model_Process::MODE_MANUAL));
$processes->walk('save');
```

And before emptying cache execute

```
$processes->walk('reindexAll');
$processes->walk('setMode', array(Mage_Index_Model_Process::MODE_REAL_TIME));
$processes->walk('save');
```

This should rebuild all indexes making sure you're retrieving the latest data from the product flat table.

Comment: I thought so at first also, but I'm 99.9% sure that this is not the issue. I tried the code posted just like you described...instantiating `Mage::app()` without emulating a store view and it worked just fine. In and out of a loop.

Comment: So I take it you only have one store in the installation? Try and using `Mage::app()->setCurrentStore([storecode]);` instead of just `Mage::app();`

Comment: I have 3 stores in my app. I used the sample data from Magento. And it worked.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but at least the frontend label value should be an array, the first value in there is the admin value.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change this way:

```
$model->addData($data);
$model->setId($attr_id);
$model->save();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tried this and still have the same issue. This issue is baffling.